# All items from a tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple, which consists of some tuple of integers and some integers, like `((1, 2), 3, (4, 5), 6)`.Now I need all integers from it. I wrote:

```
def get_all_items(iterable):
    t = []

    for each in iterable:
        if type(each) == int:
            t.append(each)
        else:
            t.extend(each)

    return tuple(t)
```

It works for me. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Do you know for sure that there is only one level of hierarchy, i.e., you don't have a tuple of tuples of tuples?

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget the cheats way

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> t = ((1, 2), 3, (4, 5), 6)
>>> literal_eval(repr(t).translate(None, '()'))
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: It's not often that code makes me laugh... I think what got me is "the cheats way"

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain

def flatten(items):
  def renest():
    for item in items:
      try:
        yield iter(item)
      except TypeError:
        yield iter([item])
  return list(chain.from_iterable(renest()))
```

Comment: @DSM yeah, I forgot `itertools` wasn't magic.

Comment: Easy to forget, because it so often is. :^)

Answer (score 1):

I think your way is fine.  Here's another way, using recursion, which will work for an arbitrarily-deeply-nested iterable structure:

```
def get_all_items(iterable):
    try:
        result = []
        for element in iterable:
            result += detuple(element)
        return result
    except TypeError:
        return [iterable]
```

Also, it may be useful to know that the operation you're describing is known as "flattening" a data structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    item if hasattr(item, '__iter__') else (item,)
        for item in iterable 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code like this

```
def get_all_items(iterable):
    t = []
    for each in iterable:
        t.extend(list(each) if isinstance(each, tuple) else [each])
    return tuple(t)

print get_all_items(((1, 2), 3, (4, 5), 6))
```

**Output**

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```